# Access SQL Database From ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, timeout

I have two websites OLD.com (classic ASP) and NEW.com (ASP.NET) - each site has its own SQL database which it can access just fine. However I need to access the OLD.com & NEW.com databases from classic asp written in OLD.com.

Here is the code i'm using in OLD.com to access NEW.com's DB:

```
Dim oCN
Set oCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCN.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=NEW.COM DB IP;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=uname;Password=pAss;Pooling=False"
```

This works just fine on my local IIS machine, but when I upload it to OLD.com it times out and gives this error:

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'
>
> Script timed out

How can this be? Whats wrong?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the classic debugging questions - does the OLD.com have network access to the database; if you have query analyser on that server can you open a sql connection using that username and password; are username and password typed correctly etc.

What query are you then performing?  The error indicates a script timeout - are you trying to retrieve something that is taking longer than the timeout - inefficient query, etc.

EDIT - for example - can the IP address of the new database be accessed from the old server?  Is there a firewall in place preventing the sql connection from one site to the other (web traffic will be allowed over port 80, not sure what port the sql connection will be going over, but may well be being blocked by either your old or new hosting providers

Comment: I don't see why OLD.com wouldn't have access to the DB, OLD.com is hosted with 1and1 and NEW.com is hosted with dataflame.co.uk.. I can't run anything on the servers themselves, but this does work on my local IIS? The query itself is:<br>oCN.Execute("SELECT CategoryID FROM tblCategories WHERE Name='" & catName2 & "' AND Active=1").fields(0).value

Comment: I had the same thought and so have just emailed them to ask exactly that. I also just put an On Error Resume Next in to see if that'd help and sure enough here's what I get back: er=[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen 20(Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. I know it exists so it must be a firewall? Is there anything else that might cause this? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Great! Its down to 1and1, their response: "If your website is pointing to the 1&1 servers, you need to use the 1&1 Database. You cannot use a different database that is on a different server or hosting provider." GRRR this makes me so angry. I spent 5 hours of my day questioning my code and trying endlessly to get this working - now i'm screwed! Thanks anyhow for helping me

Comment: Sorry to hear that - but pleased that you've managed to track it down.  Can you move the old website to the new hosting provider in order to get everything working?  After all if the new provider is running IIS then a classic asp site should run fine on it.